# mysqlhotcopy — A Database Backup Program

Tags: mysql, backup, database, mysql-replication

is the  mysqlhotcopy — A Database Backup Program best way to backup the large data in mySQL??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the thread started a few minutes ago: [How can I back up and replicate a large MySQL database?](https://serverfault.com/questions/71678/database-backup)