# backing up large database with large amount of data in a small time limit then restoring it within a small time of limit?

Tags: mysql, backup, database, mysql-replication

Backing up large database with large amount of data in a small time limit then restoring it within a small time of limit?

Any useful ideas?

Comment: how about knowing what DB, Operating System, Tools, data size?

Comment: Mind indicating the scale of time? 1 ms? 1s? 1m? 10m? 1h?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a rephrased version of http://serverfault.com/questions/71678/how-can-i-back-up-and-replicate-a-large-mysql-database would be nice to know what is meant by large and as sybreon posted, time scale?

Comment: i meant by large- a database contains millions of data rows which needs to backed-up and restored in every day basis.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do. Why do you need to backup and restore every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mylvmbackup](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/) is a tool for quickly creating backups of a MySQL server's data files. To perform a backup, mylvmbackup obtains a read lock on all tables and flushes all server caches to disk, creates a snapshot of the volume containing the MySQL data directory, and unlocks the tables again. The snapshot process takes only a small amount of time. When it is done, the server can continue normal operations, while the actual file backup proceeds.

Answer (score 3):

Use its replication facilities

Comment: +1 The most feasible suggestion. 0 downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Put the database on a hardware RAID system which allows mirroring.

For the backup, simply disable the mirroring. That will give you two exact copies of the database. Keep one "live". Run the rebuild on the other one (to clean up the possibly inconsistent state by "switching it off") and then back it up. You can take your time since the live DB still answers requests.

Enable the mirror to pull in any updates that have happened while you did a backup.

For a restore, also disable the mirror and restore into the "dead" part. After the restore has finished, enable the mirror again in such a way that the "live" database gets overwritten with the restore. You will have a few seconds of downtime for the DB server at this point since you must turn the "live" DB off and point the server to the restored DB. There is one issue to be aware of: Any changes made to the live database will be lost. Usually, this is not a bit problem, though: You must do the restore because the database is corrupt.

So you either have no live database at all or you have to run it in a "read only" state or something. If the database is not completely corrupt, you can restore the data into a third one and simply copy the few tables you need (or use the "dead" part of the mirror as a scrap space).

This approach gives you the least possible amount of downtime.

Comment: But you have to be sure that the state of the database is valid to be copied while the DB is running.

Comment: @mgb: That's the job of the RAID system. It has to make sure that the two copies of the data are always the same. Therefore, the DB is always in the same state on both copies.

Comment: yes, the disks are in the same state. but the database is not in a CONSISTENT state if you are using a non-transactional database engine, such as myisam.

Comment: @longneck: It's consistent in the live copy. In the detached mirror copy, you must run a rebuild but since that doesn't influence the live copy, customers won't notice. Then you can do a backup. This can take some time but again, the live copy isn't affected.

Comment: Sounds like an ugly hack to me

Comment: @Tom: Databases must survive a sudden power loss, so it's a creative application of a feature. Many professionals DBs today allow live backups without heavy performance cuts but if yours doesn't, this is a way out.

Comment: doesn't RAID system slow the process down as its working on two database, will this affect the live application??

Comment: A good RAID system will both make your DB faster and more reliable. Writing would make the system slower (since it has to write each block two times) but a) the RAID writes both blocks at the same time in parallel, and b) both the RAID controller and your hard disks have large caches, so most of the time, you get the speed your cables allow.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a complete copy of an entire mysql server instance with the smallest downtime using only features present in mysql server, then do the following:

1. send FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK to
   close all the table handles and stop
   new ones from being created.
2. make a
   copy the entire mysql data directory
   using your OS copy functions or a
   backup utility.
3. send UNLOCK TABLES.

if you're using a filesystem that supports volume snapshots, then you can replace #2 with a snapshot instead.

Comment: I don't think this will work with InnoDB tables.

Comment: It will work fine with InnoDB tables provided you use a filesystem snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filesystem snapshot of your Innodb database*. You will get a consistent copy of the files on restore, after InnoDB has finished rolling back any transactions which were in progress etc.

To backup, you'll need to :

1. Take a filesystem snapshot *OR* if your filesystem doesn't support it, take a block device snapshot
2. If necessary, mount the fs or block device snapshot, allowing for some filesystem repair time if needed (the db will still be online at this point)
3. Back up the mounted snapshot using your  normal backup tools
4. Unmount and/or delete the snapshot as necessary.

To restore it, shut down mysql, wipe out your old data files, then restore the files into the mysql data directory. When you restart the mysql instance, it will recover from any transactions which were in progress at the time of the backup (by rolling them back) then come up normally. This may take a while of course.

* of course you'll have some MyISAM tables in the "mysql" system database. Make sure they aren't changing during the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know what OS we're dealing with, but assuming it's a recent Linux distro, your best bet will be using LVM snapshots. The net is full of relevant recipes and tools, here's one link that lists the most popular ones:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?28,204733,204733